# Postman returns the expected 400 response, but axios doesn't throw and returns undefined in the then clause

Tags: node.js, axios

I'm currently using an [SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@unit-finance/unit-node-sdk) from a company called Unit. I'm now trying to [create a counterparty](https://docs.unit.co/payments-counterparties/#create-counterparty).

The SDK utilizes Axios under the hood.

I'm expecting the payload to return a 400 response, but somehow the Axios client isn't throwing and returns an undefined in the `then` clause.

Unit SDK allows us to inject our Axios instance.We've implemented a response receptor to get a universal logging solution. (See details below)

```
import { crossAdapter } from './axios-adaptor';
import Axios, { AxiosInstance, AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import { Logger } from '../context';

export type AxiosInstanceOpts = {
  logger?: Logger;
  validateStatus?: ((status: number) => boolean) | null | undefined;
};

export const getAxiosInstance = (opts?: AxiosInstanceOpts) => {
  const axios = Axios.create({
    adapter: crossAdapter() as any,
    transitional: {
      clarifyTimeoutError: true,
    },
    validateStatus: opts?.validateStatus,
  });

  if (opts?.logger) {
    const logger = opts.logger;
    axios.interceptors.response.use(
      (response: AxiosResponse) => {
        logger.info(
          {
            status: response.status,
            method: response.config?.method?.toUpperCase(),
            url: response.config?.url,
          },
          'Axios Response'
        );
        logger.debug(
          {
            body: response.data,
          },
          'Axios Response Body'
        );
        return response;
      },
      (error) => {
        logger.error(
          {
            err: error,
          },
          'Axios Response Error'
        );
      }
    );
  }

  return axios;
};

export type { AxiosInstance };
```

This instance is then called in a wrapper class (Poor Man's DI) that lazy loads its initialization, and makes it available to all other services.

```
 export class ClientsImpl {

  _unitClient: Unit;

  get unitClient(): Unit {
    if (!this._unitClient) {
      const unitToken = (this._headers.get('Bank-Authorization') || '').replace(
        'Bearer ',
        ''
      );
      const unitUrl = this._config.unitUrl;
      if (!unitToken) {
        throw new Error('Unit Client not available for this request');
      }

      this._unitClient = getUnitClient(unitToken, unitUrl, {
        validateStatus(status) {
          return status < 300;
        },
        logger: this._logger,
      });
    }

    return this._unitClient;
  }
}
```

I then use it in the service, like this:

```
class CounterpartyService {
   async createVerifiedCounterparty(
    userId: string,
    customerId: string,
    input: VerifiedCounterpartyInput
  ): Promise<
    Result<AchCounterparty, UnitError | UnitHttpError | UnexpectedError>
  > {
    const logger = this.context.logger;
    try {
      const { uuid } = this.context.utils;
      const { unitClient} = this.context.clients;

      const result = await unitClient.counterparties
        .create({
          type: 'achCounterparty',
          attributes,
          relationships: {
            customer: {
              data: {
                type: 'customer',
                id: customerId,
              },
            },
          },
        })
        .then((response) => Ok(response.data))
        .catch((error: any) => {
          if (error.response) {
            // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
            // that falls out of the range of 2xx
            console.log('');
            console.log(error.response.data);
            console.log(error.response.status);
            console.log(error.response.headers);
          }
          logger.error(
            { attributes, error, underlying: error?.underlying },
            'counterparties:create-verified-counterparty:error:unit-achCounterparty'
          );

          if (error?.underlying?.data?.errorCode === 'NameVerificationFailed') {
            return new Err(
              new UnitHttpError(
                UnitHttpErrors.NameVerificationFailed,
                error?.underlying?.data?.details || ''
              )
            );
          }
          return Err(error);
        });

      return result;
    } catch (e) {
      const error = unexpectedError(e);
      return Err(error);
    }
  }
}
```

But whenever I hit the the 400 response, the instance doesn't throw and continues with an undefined `then`.

I've tried the following:

- Ran the payload directly in Postman. The endpoint is behaving correctly.
- Ran Axios in a separate code sandbox. The endpoint is behaving correctly.
- Entered into node_modules and inspect the code.

Any ideas?

Here's how I'm initializing the Unit Client:

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a sneaky one, in the `getAxiosClient` function, you must `throw` the error or return a failed promise`return Promise.reject(error)`.

Leaving us with (see error callback):

```
export const getAxiosInstance = (opts?: AxiosInstanceOpts) => {
  const axios = Axios.create({
    adapter: crossAdapter() as any,
    transitional: {
      clarifyTimeoutError: true,
    },
    validateStatus: opts?.validateStatus,
  });

  if (opts?.logger) {
    const logger = opts.logger;
    axios.interceptors.response.use(
      (response: AxiosResponse) => {
        logger.info(
          {
            status: response.status,
            method: response.config?.method?.toUpperCase(),
            url: response.config?.url,
          },
          'Axios Response'
        );
        logger.debug(
          {
            body: response.data,
          },
          'Axios Response Body'
        );
        return response;
      },
      (error) => {
        logger.error(
          {
            err: error,
          },
          'Axios Response Error'
        );
        throw logger;
      }
    );
  }

  return axios;
};
```